# Evaluate $\exp\bigg(-\dfrac{x^2}{2} + 4x \bigg) \text{ as } x \to \infty.$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Compute limit of $$\exp\bigg(-\dfrac{x^2}{2} + 4x \bigg) \text{ as } x \to \infty.$$

Why is the above limit $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not like to use the definition for illustration. Instead, I am going to use the limit of a composite function for illustration. The function you have can be viewed as a composite function $h\left(x\right) = f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$, where $g\left(x\right) = -\frac{x^{2}}{2} + 4x$ and $f\left(x\right) = e^{x}$. As
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to \infty}-\frac{x^{2}}{2} + 4x = -\infty
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^{x} = 0,
\end{equation}
the solution of your problem is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x^{2}/2+4x} = 0.
\end{equation}
Strictly, you should use the $\epsilon-\delta$ language to prove it, as the type of notation $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right) = -\infty$ is not rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $e^{-x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

For $x \ge 16$
$$
 - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + 4x =  - x^2 \left( {\frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{x}} \right) \le  - \frac{{x^2 }}{4}.
$$
Thus, by the positivity and monotonicity of the exponential function
$$
0 < \exp \left( { - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + 4x} \right) \le \exp \left( { - \frac{{x^2 }}{4}} \right)
$$
for $x\geq 16$. Can you see why does this imply the claim?

Comment: there exists a $\delta$ large enough so that....

Comment: You are using the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
-\frac{x^2}{2} + 4x &= -\frac{1}{2}\left( x^2-8x \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\left((x-4)^2-16\right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^2+8
\end{align}

Comment: You man $-\tfrac12(x^2-8x)$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, yes I do. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @PNDas